# PLA v2 : Specify BIND Account

Tags: phpldapadmin

Currently I’m using the docker image in order to test the functionality of PLA V2 beta on our test environment. I would like to specify a BIND account for PLA, as anonymous binds have been disabled on our LDAP servers. Please excuse, but I’m not very experienced with docker and PHP. I’m trying to figure out where the BIND account details could be specified, but I’m not getting which file should be adjusted. On a standalone installation these settings can be specified under /etc/phpldapadmin/config.php. What would be equivalence in the docker image? /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache/config.php? Would be very thankful for some hints of if someone could point me to the correct file.

Tried to modify /var/www/html/bootstrap/cache/config.php, but without success.